# Relationship between primal and dual wavelet filter coefficients

Tags: numerical-methods, signal-processing, wavelets

I've been working with wavelets for a project, more specifically implementing the Fast Wavelet Transform, which requires the use of the dual high pass and low pass filters (for the forward FWT). In the literature (such as in Karsten Urban's "Wavelet Methods for Elliptic Partial Differential Equations,") they give the following relation for the class of Biorthogonal B-Spline wavelets:

$$
\tilde{b}_{k} = (-1)^k a_{1-k} 
$$

Where the $\tilde{b}_{k}$ are the refinement coefficients of the dual wavelet, and the $a_{k}$ are the refinement coefficients of the primal scaling function. These sequences of coefficients are known to be:

$$
\textbf{a} = \{\{-1, 0.5\}, \{0, 1\}, \{1, 0.5\}\}\\
\tilde{\textbf{b}} = \{\{0, -0.5\}, \{1, 1\}, \{2, -0.5\}\}
$$

The first element of each pair is the index k, while the second is the actual value. However, there seems to be an inconsistency since, for instance, $\tilde{b}_{0} = -0.5$ and if we use the relation, we get $\tilde{b}_{0} = (-1)^0a_{1-0} = a_{1} = 0.5$ which doesn't match.

Does anyone know what I am missing, or if I am making an error? Thank you.

Comment: @LutzLehmann That makes sense to me. I found it written as b_tilde = {0.5, -1, 0.5} in a couple of other places too. The main place I found it written as I did in the main post was the Wolfram Mathematica documentation, which could be an error on their part. I was  unsure since the only way I got my FWT algorithm to work was to take the negative of b_tilde, and I don't know why. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @LutzLehmann by the analysis detail filter, do you mean the dual high-pass filter (b_tilde)?

Comment: That depends on how you organize the language. In my use, from input signal to coefficients/encoding is the analysis phase, using the primal filters. From coefficients to output signal is the reconstruction phase, using the dual filters. // A case could be made that in digital data transmission, the data symbols, possibly from several channels, get distributed over the wavelet coefficients, a signal is constructed to transmit, and on the receiver side the data gets extracted. This might change what is considered "primal".

Comment: My first comments were wrong, detailed discussion in your follow-up question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4518674/help-with-fast-wavelet. There is only one sign variant for the dual coefficients that satisfies all the required equations between filter coefficients for bi-orthogonality. But shifts, or phase factors, are important. If you skew these, this has follow-up consequences.